# MySQL/PHP "data too long for column"

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting the "data too long for column" error when trying to insert a single row in a MySQL table. I know the db is set up right because I can insert the same data other ways with no problem. Here are the essential parts of the code. If you want to see any of the functions' full code instead of pseudocode, I'll be happy to post - just trying to avoid clutter.

Output is as follows:

> Connected to MySQL
>   Connected to database dublin
>   Data too long for column 'gpsMin' at row 1

testindex.php

```
include 'parseData.php';
parseAll("dublin");
```

parseData.php

```
function parseAll($sitename){
  function pullAndDelete($filename){} #reads data from file, deletes file
  $data = pullAndDelete($sitename);

  function parse($str){} #extracts first piece of data from data string
  function chop2($str){} #removes 2 chars from front of string
  function chop14($str){} #removes 14 chars from front of string

  #$data is put through parse and chop functions several times -
  #take first piece of data, chop it off, take new first piece, chop again, etc.
  #Function calls up through relevant one:

  $radio=parse($data);
  $short1=chop14($data);
  $antenna=parse($short1);
  $short2=chop14($short1);
  $gpsmaj=parse($short2);
  $short3=chop14($short2);
  $gpsmin=parse($short3);
```

At this point, echo'ed called to strlen() function produces this output:
Radio: 0 Strlen: 1
Antenna: 0 Strlen: 1
GPS Major: 0 Strlen: 1
GPS Minor: 0 Strlen: 1

```
  function writeToDB($site, $a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g, $h, $b1, $b2, $temp, $d, $t)
  {
  mysql_connect(xxx,xxx,xxx) or die(mysql_error());
  echo "Connected to MySQL<br />";

  mysql_select_db("scada") or die(mysql_error());
  echo "Connected to table ".$site."<br />";

  mysql_query("INSERT INTO ".$site." (radio, antenna, gpsMaj, gpsMin, acpwr,
   generator, blank1, blank2, battery1, battery2, temperature, date, time)
   VALUES($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g, $h, $b1, $b2, $temp, $d, $t)")
  or die(mysql_error());
  echo "Data inserted into table ".$site;
  }

  writeToDB($sitename, $radio, $antenna, $gpsmaj, $gpsmin, $acpwr, $generator,
   $blank1, $blank2, $batt1, $batt2, $temperature, $mysqldate, $mysqltime);
} #end parseAll()
```

So the db is set properly, and the strlen() function tells me the data is the right length. I don't see anything getting added to it in any way, and the first three (radio, antenna, gpsmaj) go in just fine. I've got another version of this function in a file called dbconnector.php, which works fine. I can't find a difference between the two.

Thanks in advance!

**Edits:**
The column datatype is binary.
The var value is 0.

SHOW CREATE TABLE dublin;
CREATE TABLE `dublin` (
   `idsiteData` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `radio` binary(1) DEFAULT NULL,
   `antenna` binary(1) DEFAULT NULL,
   `gpsMaj` binary(1) DEFAULT NULL,
   `gpsMin` binary(1) DEFAULT NULL,
   `acpwr` binary(1) DEFAULT NULL,
   `gener...

Vardump on 'gpsmin' shows this:

> string(1) "0"

Not sure I did the second vardump right, but here's the last line, which followed a bunch of "undefined variable" errors:

> string(157) "INSERT INTO (radio, antenna, gpsMaj, gpsMin, acpwr, generator, blank1, blank2, battery1, battery2, temperature, date, time) VALUES(, , , , , , , , , , , , )"

Comment: whats the  column datatype? what does var_dump() on the var show?

Comment: Newline character at the end of the file, maybe?

Comment: What is the actual value of $gpsMin? You probably also want to add the actual generated query, and be sure to escape your data properly as well before using it in mysql_query -- unless you can guarantee that all the values are usable in their current form directly in the query.

Comment: Assign `"INSERT INTO ".$site." (radio, antenna, gpsMaj, gpsMin, acpwr,
   generator, blank1, blank2, battery1, battery2, temperature, date, time)
   VALUES($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g, $h, $b1, $b2, $temp, $d, $t)"` to a variable, dump it and include that in your question, please.

Comment: Also, execute `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for whichever table this is hitting.

Comment: Finally, for the sake of your own sanity, read about [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). It's not relevant to your bug, but it *is* relevant to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the SQL query generated, I think the variables you are trying to insert as binaries are actually `null` or something.

What may work is by int-casting all your inputs as such:

```
$a = (int)$a;
$b = (int)$b;
$c = (int)$c;
// ... do the rest for all of your binary variables
```

(Even if it doesn't fix your problem here, it is always good practice to int-cast things which you really need a zero instead of a `null`. PHP is sometimes sloppy when it comes to distinguishing between zeros and nulls )

Comment: Done. It didn't fix the problem but I'll leave it in there. Thanks!

Comment: @KatherineSkipper Sorry it didn't really help you... I'll look into what else may be the problem

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I stuck two variables in there both named $d. That's what I get for being overly efficient. Thanks all!